# How to create array of multiple objects from object that represents objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to converts:  `{port:{0: 23, 1: 22},protocol:{0: "http",1:' "https"}}`

to:        `[{port: 23, protocol: 'http' },{port: 22, protocol: 'https' }]`

I already wrote function to do it manually.

Is there any lodash function that does that? or manipulate an existing function to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a single lodash function that does that, but you can create a function via `_.flow()` to get the desired result.

You can convert the object to an array of arrays that contain the label and values, `_.unzip()` to transpose, and then map to objects using `_.zipObject()`:

```js
const obj = { port: {0: 23, 1: 22}, protocol: {0: "http",1: "https"} };

const fn = _.flow([
  o => _.map(o, (v, k) => [k, ..._.values(v)]), // convert to an array of label, ...values
  _.unzip, // transpose
  ([labels, ...values]) => _.map(values, v => _.zipObject(labels, v)) // create the ojects
]);

const result = fn(obj);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

This could be one approach using vanillajs.

Map all the ports and the protocols to two different arrays. 
Then compose your final array getting the values from the two built arrays. 
In this way you will have a linear complexity `O(n)`.

```js
const a = { port: {0: 23, 1: 22}, protocol: {0: "http",1: "https"} };
const ports = Object.values(a.port);
const protocols = Object.values(a.protocol);
const finalArr = ports.map((port, ind) => ({ port, protocol: protocols[ind] }));
console.log(finalArr);
```

Or you can use `zip` method of loadash:

```js
const a = { port: {0: 23, 1: 22}, protocol: {0: "http",1: "https"} };
const values = Object.values(a).map(e => Object.values(e));
const zipped = _.zip(...values).map(([port, protocol]) => ({ port, protocol }));
console.log(zipped);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you are counting on the name of the properties. also, I didn't look for implementation but an existing lib/lodash function that does that.

Comment: @StavAlfi I did use the props because it looked like your objects were static. By the way added an implementation with loadash too which does not even rely on the key names

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate the entries from the objects and take the inner keys as keys for the outer array and vice versa.

```js
var data = { port: { 0: 23, 1: 22 }, protocol: { 0: "http", 1: "https" } },
    result = Object.entries(data).reduce((r, [k, o]) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([i, v]) => {
            r[i] = r[i] || {};
            r[i][k] = v;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I didn't look for implementation but an existing lib/lodash function that does that.